# wp_reset_query() or wp_reset_postdata()

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm getting confused with this so I ask with an example:

```
    <ul class="prod">
    <?php   $woop = new WP_Query($wol);
    while ( $woop->have_posts() ) : $woop->the_post(); global $prod; ?>

                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $woop->post, $prod );?>    

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </ul>
```

In this example should I use `wp_reset_query()` or `wp_reset_postdata()`?

What I understand is that I had to use `wp_reset_postdata()` after every custom `WP_Query()` and `wp_reset_query()` after every loop using `query_posts()`.

Is that simple as that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never have to use `wp_reset_query()`, which is only used to restore `$wp_query` and global post data to the original main query when using `query_posts()` (which you [should never use](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/64331)).

Instead, you should only be using `wp_reset_postdata()` when you want to restore the global `$post` variable of the main query loop after a secondary query loop using `new WP_Query()`. **You have used this correctly in your example.**